# Best way to define a constant identifier?

Tags: java, android

In my java application one of my objects has exactly one value from a set of values. Now I wonder how to define them to increase the performance:

`private static final String ITEM_TYPE1= "type1"`

`private static final int ITEM_TYPE1= 1`

Does defining int better than string? (I should convert the value to string so I like to define as string but just fearing for performance reasons because comparing ints is simpler than srtings maybe)

**EDIT**: **I am aware of enums but I just want to know whether ints has more performance than strings or not? This depends on how JDK and JRE handle the undergoing. (In Android dalvik or ART ..)**

Comment: I, personally, would use ints. But you could also use another structure, ENUMS, if you are dealing with different types/values for your group of constants. Take a look here:https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

Comment: I am aware of enums but I just want to know whether ints has more performance than strings or not? This depends on how ART or Dalvik handle the undergoing.. @AsierAranbarri

Comment: Yup, if you know *all possible values at compile time*, use enums.

Comment: Use ints, not Strings, you'll avoid using the String pool and store unnecesary values there. Or enums.

Comment: What kind of "types" are these constants representing? You know that java has a way to express the "type" of something, and that would be its "class". So what are you actually trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 3):

> In my java application one of my objects has exactly one value from a set of values

That is what java [enums](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) are for.

Regarding the question "have ints more performance than strings", that is almost nonsensical.

You are talking about static constants. Even if they are used a 100 or a 1000 times in your app, performance doesn't matter here. What matters is to write code that is easy to read and maintain. Because then the JIT can kick in and turn it into nicely optimized machine code.

Please understand: premature optimisation is the root of all evil! Good or bad performance of your app depends on many other factors, definitely not on representing constants as ints or strings.

Beyond that: the **type** of some thing in Java should reflect its **nature**. If it is a string, make it a string (like when you want to mainly use it as string, and concatenate it to other strings). When you have numbers and deal with them as numbers, make it an int.

Comment: Thank you. but anyway your answer is conflicting with the other one and it seems to be a bit subjective discussion

Comment: @Saleh Sure. There are real differences between the two types. But my point is: in practical reality, that difference makes not "enough" of a difference to be noticeable regarding runtime performance. Thus worrying about it is almost for sure a waste of energy. If at all, we are talking *nanoseconds* here. What matters to your users will be a great design and an "overall performance" that meets their needs. This means your end to end feature has to perform. And that you achieve by making the correct decisions on an architectural level!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, an `int` has always a fixed size which it uses in memory, on most systems it's 4 bytes (I guess on Java always).

A `String` is a complex type which means that it takes not only the bytes of the actual string data but also additional like the length of the string and so on.

So if you have the choice between `String` and `int`, you should always chose `int`. it does not take so much place and is faster to operate with.